# snakemake: correct quoting when using singularity

Tags: snakemake

I want to run the following shell command

```
shell:
    """
    Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('{input.markdown}', output_dir = 'output/{wildcards.version}', params = list(datapath = '../data/{wildcards.version}', max_lab_days = {config[max_lab_days]}, seed = {config[seed]}))"
    """
```

everything is fine in normal mode but breaks down when setting `--use-singularity`. I guess this is come quoting related issue since `singularity exec` adds another layer of quotes here, right?

So, I guess my question is how to avoid this quotation hell - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

okay, turns out the single quotes, ', are the problem - never use them in a snakemake shell command or it will not be portable to singularity execution. Fortunately one may escape them for the Rscript -e command by replacing ' with \".

Is that really necessary?

Comment: We had some recent improvements to automatic quoting which will be in the next release. Maybe you can try latest master and report a bug if it still not works for you. Thanks!